# Inserting Row in Excel Takes a long time

Tags: excel, performance, insert, rows

I have an excel document (10 sheets). 1 sheet has at this point about 1600 rows and about 148 columns of information. There are no formula's in this sheet.

At first I thought it was a problem with my Macro. But it turns out manually inserting a row (or deleting) gives the same problem: a 14 second delay (for ONE ROW!). I've tried deleting all conditional formatting, Data Validation, (deleting hidden graphs that get there data from a different sheet). I've tried turning of Auto Calculation (which I also do in the Macro), I've tried inserting/deleting a row in "Design Mode"> But nothing seems to help.

One version of my file (I have different back-ups) seems to have fixed it. But I cannot reproduce this in my current file. I don't know what the fix was.

I've scoured the internet for solutions but have yet to find one. I'm running on excel 2010. Who knows the trick I need? Or is updating to excel 2016 my best option?

cheers!

Comment: What about the other sheets, are there formula that refer to that sheet?  Are there a lot of volatile formula, like INDIRECT, ADDRESS, or OFFSET in the workbook?  Both of these conditions will force a recalc.  The best option is to try to turn the calculation to manual at the beginning of the code and turn them back to automatic at the end.

Comment: Your question is too vague to give a for-sure answer. It depends on way too many things. For example if you use a lot of `SUMPRODUCT` formulas that reference full columns (e.g. `SUMPRODUCT(A:A,...)`) this could easily pretty drastically slow down your calculation times, but this is just one example. @ScottCraner's comment is also valid that too many volatile formulas could be bogging down your spreadsheet.

Comment: Is the file size also large compared to what you would expect? Check for used range and delete all the blank rows and columns beyond your data and save the file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments : As I have indicated; the entire workbook uses almost no formulas. There a a few "=SUM()" Formula's on other sheets which refer to cells within that sheet, a "=TODAY()" Formula, and a "=TEXT()" formula, also referring to cells within the sheet. On the Sheet in question there are no formula's at all. @PankajR The file size is 3MB (2MB if I delete all the graphs). I don't know if this is larger then one should expect. I will try to delete the unused range of columns and rows, though I have to figure out how.

Comment: @RubenTheater Just select all the blank rows till the end (entire row) and hit Ctrl + minus combination. Same goes for columns

Comment: @PankajR That seems simple enough, and I would have thought of that myself, if that were not the entire issue: deleting and inserting rows. Furthermore: getting to row number 1000000 is a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The three primary causes of recalculation lag are calculation, event handling (due to a Worksheet_Change) and (to a lesser degree) screen updating.

Put this 'helper' sub procedure in a public module code sheet.

```
Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .AutoRecover.Enabled = bTGGL   'no interruptions with an auto-save
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Use it like this,

```
sub main()
    appTGGL btggl:=false

    'do everything you have to do here

    appTGGL
end sub
```

You can add or remove application environment settings as you see fit.

If the problem turns out to be a badly written Worksheet_Change then post it here or on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) for improvement,

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the problem does not seem to be the Macro; as I explained the problem even occurs in "Design Mode" (which should disable all macro code, right?). Anyway: I also tried disabling all the Worksheet_Change code just to be sure; no luck.

Answer (score 0):

quick update: somehow the problem is fixed when I remove to other sheets. These sheets are not connected by formula references in any ways. Both sheets have (flat) information implanted by macro's, but after the macro is done it's just flat information. I've tried disabling al relevant macro's but this didn't solve the issue. Only deleting the other sheets: If i deleted 1 of the sheets the time would go from 14 sec to 7 seconds, and if I deleted the other as well it would go to 0 seconds.

It seems as though somehow these sheets are connected by some kind of calculation (outside of the macros) but I cannot imagine what this might be. Any Ideas?

Comment: Further update: I ended up deleting the two sheets in question and recreating them exactly the same way (as far as I know). This seems to have fixed the issue, though I still don't know what te problem was.